# Javascript -Node.js When do i need to 'require' a module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm fairly new to Node.js and server side programming in general, and still a bit confused about basic Node rules. To start an http server, I need to require the http module. The server itself returns a request and a response object, which (as I understand, correct me if I'm wrong) are both eventEmitters and stream objects. I can still use methods like req.on() and res.write() without requiring the stream and eventEmitter modules. However, when I try to use the pipe function req.pipe(res), an error occurs saying that the pipe function is not defined. I assume this happens because I didn't include the stream module. How come I can use certain stream functions without requiring modules, but not others?

Comment: If it says res.pipe is not defined, then res isn't what you think it is.  You need to require a module when it exposes methods you need, i.e. `path`, `os`, `fs` etc.

Comment: No, your understanding is correct. You don't need to import a module to use methods defined in it when someone gives you an instance that has the methods. You only need to import it when you want to use an export, like the `EventEmitter` constructor.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you did, but you cannot pipe `res` back into `res` itself. Maybe try `req.pipe(res)`?

Comment: @Bergi sorry yea that's what I meant, it was a typo

Comment: Hm, [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) say "*It implements the [Readable Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) interface*" so if this does not work it might be a bug. Can you please post a [mcve] that produces the error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're pretty new to Javascript as well, but I'll try to do my best to explain this.
`require` basically imports an object so you can use the functionality it provides. But if you already have an object, then you don't need to import (`require`) because it already exists.

For instance, if you want to create a stream, then you'll need to `require` it since creating a stream is a functionality you need to import. However, your function can still take a `stream` as a parameter and use it since it already exists.

```
const Stream = require('stream');

// need to require stream since we'd like to use it to create an object
const mystream = new Stream();
```

--

```
// no need to require stream here since you're given the object
function doSomethingWithStream(streamObject){
    streamObject.on('data', () => { /* do something */ });
}
```

So in your case you don't need to `require` `stream` since you already have the object. Although your `res` object should have a pipe method (see example below), but it won't work because piping only works from a `Readable` stream to a `Writable` stream and `res` is a `Writable` stream (see Node `Stream` docs).

```
const express= require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/has-pipe',(req, res) => {
    const success = !!res.pipe; // true if res.pipe exists
    req.pipe(res) // Readable stream to Writable stream
    res.send({ success }); // returns true
})

const port = 3000
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example server running on port 3000`))
```

Comment: I think I understand a little. Would it be because that the stream module is included within the http module? Sorry, I'm still getting used to modules and importing. In normal JS I usually only need to use global objects

Comment: Could be, but it's not necessary. Javascript is a duck-typed language and doesn't really care about the type of the object, just the functionality it has. So it could be that the developers of the `http` module created a custom stream object that works just like the one in the `stream` module.

I guess the key takeaway is that there's no magic. You `require` a module because YOU need it, not anyone else. You `require` it and use it to build what you need. Objects are then just passed around. Once they're created, it doesn't matter how they were created; what matters is what they can do.

Comment: For instance, see in my last example (the one with `express`). I `require` `express` because I need to create an instance to build my functionality, but in the function I pass to `app.get`, I have access to `req` and `res`, so I don't need to require anything for them. They have the functionality I need and that's all I care about. Doesn't really matter how those objects were created since I already have them available.

Comment: Although there are some modules that are `require`d and actually modify existing objects, but those aren't as common. An example of such module is `datejs`, which augments the global `Date` object to provide it with additional functionality.